# How to work with Kotlin Coroutines Flow UI State? UI State changes after screenrotation using stateflow

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, viewmodel, kotlin-stateflow

I created a Activity and ViewModel for to collect Stateflows to toggle views.

This is my ActivityClass

@AndroidEntryPoint
class LoggingActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private var _bind : ActivityLoggingBinding? = null

private val bind : ActivityLoggingBinding get() = _bind!!

private lateinit var email : String

private val loggingViewModel : LoggingViewModel by viewModels()



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState : Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    _bind = ActivityLoggingBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(bind.root)

    getExtras()
    collectToggleViewFlow()

    bind.btnSave.setOnClickListener {
        loggingViewModel.toggleView()
    }

}

private fun getExtras() {
    email = intent.extras?.getString("email")!!

    when (email) {
        "No User" -> loggingViewModel.toggleView()
        else -> loggingViewModel.toggleView()
    }
}

private fun collectToggleViewFlow() {
    lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
        loggingViewModel.toggleFlow.collect{
            when(it){
                is LoggingViewModel.ToggleView.SignUp -> {
                    bind.inputName.visible()
                    bind.inputPhoneNo.visible()
                }
                is LoggingViewModel.ToggleView.SignIn -> {
                    bind.inputName.inVisible()
                    bind.inputPhoneNo.inVisible()
                }
                is LoggingViewModel.ToggleView.Nothing -> Unit
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

This is my ViewModel Class

@HiltViewModel
class LoggingViewModel @Inject constructor(private val firebaseAuthRepo : FirebaseAuthRepo,) : ViewModel() {

```
private val _toggleFlow : MutableStateFlow<ToggleView> = MutableStateFlow(ToggleView.Nothing)

val toggleFlow : StateFlow<ToggleView> get() = _toggleFlow


fun toggleView() {
    when (toggleFlow.value) {
        ToggleView.SignIn -> _toggleFlow.value = ToggleView.SignUp
        ToggleView.SignUp -> _toggleFlow.value = ToggleView.SignIn
        else -> _toggleFlow.value = ToggleView.SignIn
    }
}


sealed class ToggleView {
    object Nothing : ToggleView()
    object SignIn : ToggleView()
    object SignUp : ToggleView()
}
```

}

I created the button click event to toggle between views visibility. When I click the SIGNUP button it works fine.

[Portrait mode image1 | toggleview by clicking button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESjUB.png)

[Portrait mode image2 | toggleview by clicking button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8fPu.png)

When I rotate my phone to landscape, without the buttonclick event it toggle's view automatically, I don't know why?

[Landscape mode image | toggleview automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUfvq.png)

Comment: Looks to me like each call to `onCreate` will result in a call to `getExtras`, which in turn will call the viewmodel's `toggleView`-function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I got a solution. I called the getExtras function when the viewmodel collects Nothing state so it will call once.